# What does it mean if my bank account has a credit?

Tags: accounts

I have been using one of my bank account on very occasional basis, so I never know how much money is in. Just checked my balance on the phone and it says £130 in credit. Does it mean I still have £130 or did I go into overdraft of £130? Very puzzled...

Answer (score 6):

'In credit' means you have money in your account. It would say 'overdrawn' or something similar if you went into overdraft.